# Is it bad to couple two forms together?

Tags: c#, coupling

It seems like a form should be stand-alone, but here's my dilemma:

I have an object called `GameMap`. It exists on a `MapForm` which is all fine and good. It can edit itself, etc. However, I also have a `TilesetForm` and `LayerForm` I was passing in the `GameMap` to these objects - but then I found out I also needed to pass the CurrentLayer between the layer form and map editor so they could edit and be selected on the other form. Next thing I know - dependencies between the two are pretty much tied together. The tileset lives its sole purpose to serve the `MapForm`, so does it map sense to just couple them together?

How can I make this explicit - I can't use the constructor because the form might not be active - right now I just called `SwitchContext` when a new map form is focused.

Comment: I can imagine photoshop does this in places, you can obviously see the drawbacks in this approach so I'd say try to avoid it as much as possible, maybe have a middle ground for the information to be accessible from

Comment: Limitations that prevent you from implementing the right patterns and proper decoupling plague winforms everywhere. That's why WPF was invented to replace it.

Comment: @HighCore I'm curious - how does something like WPF solve this problem?

Comment: @VaughanHilts WPF provides a serious DataBinding Framework, DataTemplates, Commands, and everything needed to implement the MVVM pattern.

Comment: You could create a separate class that encapsulates all of this loose information into a single place and then simply make every form aware of it (via parameter or property).  Then each one can use it, change it, whatever you choose to allow.  But then there's sharing instead of passing loose bits.

Comment: @HighCore You can use proper design and reduce the coupling in winform just as easily as you can in WPF, most people just don't.

Comment: @HighCore I think we're getting a bit off topic here. :) My question is how to tolerate WinForms and this coupling - I can't port to WPF.

Comment: @HighCore If you aren't capable of writing winform applications up to an appropriate standard then perhaps you should refrain from contributing so frequently to such questions.  Reducing the coupling can be done equally effectively in either paradigm using primarily the same techniques.  WPF has much more robust data binding, but that's an entirely different issue.  Following a standard MVC pattern, and modularizing UI components from each other can be done quite effectively in winforms, despite the fact that so few people choose to leverage that ability.

Answer (score 2):

You handle this through using events.

Rather than passing an instance of the map to the tileset and having the tile set directly manipulating the map when something happens, define an event in tileset whenever important things happen.  The map can then subscribe to those events and perform some action.  The tileset then doesn't need to know anything at all about the map.

If it doesn't make sense for the map to logically "own" the tileset, then it wouldn't even be subscribing to the events directly.  It might make sense to have a 3rd party (some higher level concept) that "knows about" both the tile set and the map; it would then subscribe an event handler to the tile set, and call some appropriate method on the map in the event handler.  (This method is so that even this high level concept doesn't know about the specific UI implementations of the map.)

Comment: +1 for a helpful answer. This seems like a decent way to handle things. At the very worst, at least it's one way coupling to the master object which seems okay.